# How to assign existing multiple Azure policies to multiple resources with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-policy, infrastructure-as-code

I am using open source Terraform with AZURE and I am stuck at following task. Please advise if you have better solutions.

I have the IDs of Azure policies in a list

```
  variable "existing_policy_ids" {
     "policy-id1",
     "policy-id2",
     "policy-id3",
      ......
    }
```

I need to assign all these policies to resource group in Azure dynamically. The resource group has count meta argument like this:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "my-rg" {
  count    = var.environment == "dev" ? 1 : 2
  name     = "my-rg-${count.index}"
  location = var.rg_location
}
```

Now the question is - How should the policy assignment look like, since there are multiple policies (10) while resource group can be 1 or 2 depending on environment. Means I can not use standard way of count or for_each?!

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group_policy_assignment" "assign-policy" {

  count        = length(azurerm_resource_group.my-rg.id)
  name         = "${azurerm_resource_group.my-rg[count.index].name}"
  policy_definition_id = var.existing_policy_id[count.index]  # ISSUE
  resource_group_id = azurerm_resource_group.my-rg[count.index].id   # ISSUE

}
```

Now the last 2 lines of Policy assignment block is where I am stuck. If I use `count.index` then the counter will only run once or max 2 times. While policies are more than 2.

Now how do I code that each `resource_group` that gets created, is assigned all the policies I have in the variable `existing_policy_ids.`

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have iterate over a cumulative list of both `existing_policy_ids` and the number of your `azurerm_resource_group`. In your case,you could use [setproduct](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/setproduct) for that.

```
locals {
  cummulative_list = setproduct(
        range(length(azurerm_resource_group.my-rg)), 
        var.existing_policy_ids)  
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group_policy_assignment" "assign-policy" {
  count     = length(local.cummulative_list)
  name      = azurerm_resource_group.my-rg[local.cummulative_list[count.index][0]].name
  policy_definition_id = local.cummulative_list[count.index][1] 
  resource_group_id = azurerm_resource_group.my-rg[local.cummulative_list[count.index][0]].id   
}
```

Comment: This seems to do the job. Thanks. However, now the headache is passing parameters to polcies in setproduct like iterations.

Comment: @ZeeA You can make a new question about that.